# BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress() not updating property

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using Backgroundworker to show loader during processing.But loader(Progressbar) does not updates and only updates after completion.whenever worker ProgressChanged event is called , it never updates value of progressbar label.This may be due to async behaviour of ProgressChanged event.I am new to threads please help.

```
 void  worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {


        bool isCompletedSuccessfully = true;
        FileSQLHelper objSqlHelper = new FileSQLHelper();
        PGPUtil utilityObj = new PGPUtil();


            #region Outcoming
            try
            {

                objSqlHelper.OpenConnection();
                List<File> fileList = objSqlHelper.GetFilesList();
                double totalRecord = fileList.Count();
                int counter = 1;

                foreach (var Fileitem in fileList)
                {

                    double progressStatus = (counter / totalRecord) * 100;
                    (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress((int)progressStatus);

                    //  my code here

                    counter++;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isCompletedSuccessfully = false;
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");

            }
            finally
            {
                if (isCompletedSuccessfully == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Completed Successfully!", "Information");
                }
                else if (isCompletedSuccessfully == false)
                {
                    // MessageBox.Show("Completed Unsuccessfully!", "Information");
                }

            }
            #endregion



}

 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
      //  worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

Function called when we report progress

```
    void  worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; 

        } 
        catch( Exception exp )
        {
            throw exp;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: It isn't relevant to your current issue, but `throw exp;` should be changed to `throw;`

Comment: Whack a breakpoint on `pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;` and debug the code. How many times does it get hit?

Comment: @mjwills it gets hits every time we call "reportprogress" in foreach loop and it shows async behavior.Means this line "pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage" hits randomly.And function containing this code does not completes its execution due to its async behavior.But it do completes its behavior when loop reaches to end.Actually control shifts to calling thread after this line of code.that is why it is not updating.

Comment: @mm8 ReportProgress is in loop, so it is not called once.

Comment: But what are doing in the loop?

Answer (score -2):

I guess you need to introduce something right after you are assigning the ProgressPercentage value to the ProgressBar control, something similar to what **Application.DoEvents()** was doing in WinForms. In WPF, you can achieve the same via [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx). See how it works, it could take time to understand and implement the solution with this. See this code sample from MSDN-

```
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
public void DoEvents()
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}

public object ExitFrame(object f)
{
    ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;

    return null;
}
```

However, if you just want to move on faster, you can still use **Application.DoEvents()** here, but only after importing *System.Windows.Forms.dll* in your WPF project (which is kind of an ugly solution).

Comment: Please do not _ever_ suggest anyone _ever_ call `Application.DoEvents()`. That is _always_ horrible advice. And it is doubly so in the context of a question involving `BackgroundWorker`, given that the whole point of `BackgroundWorker` is to avoid having to do silly hacks like calling `Application.DoEvents()`.